# Inconsistent results with Monte Carlo solutions to similar problems in probability

Tags: r, monte-carlo, uniform-distribution

I am presently going through the book *Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions* and implementing Monte Carlo solutions to most of the problems in R to get familiar with the language, and have come to a puzzling inconsistency in what is effective for getting the right answers. Consider the following problem, #39:

> In a laboratory, each of a handful of thin 9-inch glass rods had one tip
>   marked with a blue dot and the other with a red. When the laboratory
>   assistant tripped and dropped them onto the concrete floor, many broke into
>   three pieces. For these, what was the average length of the fragment with
>   the blue dot?

To solve this problem, I drew three numbers from the continuous uniform distribution offered by R, each on the default interval [0,1]. These were summed and then the quotient of the first of these numbers to the total times nine was returned. The process was then repeated many times in the typical Monte Carlo fashion to give a very nearly correct answer: ~2.99 inches. I then went on to attempt a similar approach with problem #42:

> (a) If a stick is broken in two at random, what is the average length of the smaller piece? (b) (For calculus students.) What is the average ratio of the smaller length to the larger?

In this case, for (a), only two numbers were drawn to represent the lengths of the two pieces and the quotient of the smaller of the two to the total was returned. (No explicit length was ever given and so the idea is to deal with fractions of the original intact stick's length.) A similar procedure was carried out for (b). Both procedures returned incorrect results. The answers given for (a) and (b) respectively were ~0.307 and almost exactly 0.5.

What *was* effective for (a) was generating a single number from the uniform distribution described above, calling it $
\text{split}$, and then, if $\text{split}$ was less than 0.5, returning that number, or else returning $1 - \text{split}$. Such a procedure was also carried out for (b), returning $\frac{\text{split}}{1 - \text{split}}$ if $\text{split}$ was less than 0.5 or else returning $\frac{1 - \text{split}}{\text{split}}$. Both of these returned very nearly correct answers, respectively: ~0.25 and ~0.386.

I can't account for this inconsistent behavior. What is the cause? I have a faint inkling some sort of degrees of freedom issue is involved here but that doesn't explain why the solution to the first one was effective.

Comment: Could you explain what is "inconsistent"?  To which "behavior" are you referring?

Comment: The inconsistency in question is that, in the first problem, I can generate *three* random numbers and normalize their lengths to sum to 9 to serve as the *three* parts of the broken stick, and get the right answer, but, in the latter, I cannot generate *two* random numbers to serve as the lengths of the *two* parts of the broken stick, but need the other method I described above.

Comment: You got lucky in your solution to the first problem.  The reason the answer is $3$ is wholly unrelated to your simulation.  Your simulation accidentally produces $3$ as the answer because you have generated three identically distributed variables $U_1,U_2,U_3$ and computed the expectation of $U_1/(U_1+U_2+U_3)$. Replacing $U_1$ in the numerator by $U_2$ or $U_3$ will give the same expectation--but since the sum of those three fractions is $1$, obviously each expectation must equal $1/3$.  You could have given the $U_i$ *literally any* distribution supported on the positive real numbers!

Comment: Ah ... I will see if generating two splits gives the right answer in this case just as well.

Comment: A better approach is to formulate a probability model based on your analysis of each question.  As you have seen, merely getting the right answer is no indication that you have performed an adequate or correct analysis.

Comment: Looking at the solutions section, the rationale for the solution given for #39 is very similar to what you said and what the code did:

*Assuming these rods broke at random, the principle of symmetry says that each fragment—blue-dotted, middle, and red-dotted segment—would have the same distribution and the same mean. Since the means have to add to 9 inches, the blue-dotted segments average about 3 inches.*

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by formulating a probability model based on the analysis of each question. The problems in the book are pretty heterogeneous and accordingly, except for some utility functions shared in common, no two simulations have been quite alike.

Comment: A simulation implements a probability model.  Therefore you should at least be aware of *what* probability model each of your simulations is implementing and of the assumptions that underlie it.  Otherwise you have little basis to trust the results. For instance, I would answer #39 entirely differently, because I know enough about glass rods to realize they will not break according to any "principle of symmetry": the chances of a break are greater at certain points in the middle than at either end. This realization would lead to a different solution and even to different coding strategies.

Comment: Well, in real life, that would not surprise me at all but the book assumes an "ideal" glass rod—insert the old joke about a spherical horse moving in simple harmonic motion. The goal here is not to achieve the most empirically realistic outcome but one that mirrors in the Monte Carlo world the analytic solutions given and *their* respective assumptions. Until now I have had relatively little difficulty and no occasion to ask any questions until fairly close to the end. The mappings between the problem descriptions and solutions have been quite clear other than in this instance.

Comment: Indeed, in a number of cases, there was no need to debug the solution at all.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that (1) there usually is more than one "self-evident" model for these toy mathematical textbook questions and (2) you *must* be clear about what model you are attempting to implement when you do a simulation.  Just doing a simulation and checking that it produces a mean that is "close" to the textbook answer accomplishes little.  If the textbook answer specifies the *entire distribution* of a random variable, you will learn more by attempting to reproduce that distribution.

Comment: I essentially agree with this. For instance, one problem asks how likely it is that a random chord drawn across a circle is longer than the radius. The solutions section offers three different ways of interpreting this problem and when I looked at it, it was clear that I had in fact implemented the third: "Assume that the chord is determined by two points chosen so that their positions are independently evenly distributed over the circumference of the original circle", rather than one of the others, and gotten the according answer. These details are not lost on me.

Comment: Because of the very concrete nature of computer programs, necessarily one is committed to very visible assumptions about the process in question.

Comment: Anal addendum: I should have said *most* computer programs. Conceivably the software learned by an advanced neuromorphic processor could have the vague character of much of human thought. But let's just say software for an ordinary computer with a von Neumann architecture.